# PowerShell not executing AWS CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, yaml, aws-cloudformation

Here is the problem: Im working on an .yaml Cloud Formation script for AWS, the objective is to deploy a Windows 2016 / 2019 Server, and execute some commands in PowerShell, but none of the commands are excuting.

Here is the full script:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09

Description: |
  Plantilla para desplegar una instancia EC2 de Windows Server en eu-west-1.

Parameters:
  vpcId:
    Description: VPC sobre la que se desplegara el servidor
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC::Id

  subnetId:
    Description: Listado de subredes disponibles
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id

  apserSecurityGroupId:
    Description: Debe llamarse SG-Apser y existir en la VPC seleccionada
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup::Id

  serverType:
    Description: Imagen (AMI) del servidor
    Type: String
    Default: 'WindowsServer2019'
    AllowedValues: [WindowsServer2016, WindowsServer2019]

  instanceSize:
    Description: Tamano de la instancia EC2
    Type: String
    Default: 't3.large'
    AllowedValues: [t3.large, t3.xlarge, t3.2xlarge, m5.large, m5.xlarge, m5.2xlarge]

  volumeSize:
    Description: Tamano (GiB) del volumen de la instancia
    Type: Number
    Default: 30
    MinValue: 30
    MaxValue: 1000

  adminPassword:
    Description: Contrasena para la cuenta de Administrador
    Type: String
    NoEcho: true
    MinLength: 8
    MaxLength: 20

Metadata:
  AWS::CloudFormation::Interface:
    ParameterGroups:
    -
      Label:
        default: "Configuracion de Red"
      Parameters:
        - vpcId
        - subnetId
        - apserSecurityGroupId
    -
      Label:
        default: "Configuracion del servidor"
      Parameters:
        - serverType
        - instanceSize
        - volumeSize
        - adminPassword
    ParameterLabels:
      vpcId:
        default: "VPC para despliegue"
      subnetId:
        default: "Subnet para despliegue"
      apserSecurityGroupId:
        default: "SecurityGroup de Apser"
      serverType:
        default: "Tipo de servidor (S.O.)"
      instanceSize:
        default: "Tamano de la instancia"
      volumeSize:
        default: "Tamano del volumen"
      adminPassword:
        default: "Contrasena de Administrador"

Mappings:
  serverAMI:
    WindowsServer2016:
      value: "ami-059cafee566b7248c"
    WindowsServer2019:
      value: "ami-01925800085c95bea"

Resources:
  server:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Instance'
    Properties:
      InstanceType: !Ref instanceSize
      ImageId: !FindInMap
        - serverAMI
        - !Ref serverType
        - value
      SubnetId: !Ref subnetId
      BlockDeviceMappings:
        - DeviceName: /dev/sda1
          Ebs:
            VolumeSize: !Ref volumeSize
            Encrypted: true
      CreditSpecification:
        CPUCredits: standard
      DisableApiTermination: false # DEBE SER SIEMPRE TRUE!
      SecurityGroupIds:
        - !GetAtt securityGroup.GroupId
        - !Ref apserSecurityGroupId
      IamInstanceProfile: apser-multirole
      UserData:
        'Fn::Base64': !Sub |
          <powershell>
          Rename-Computer -NewName ${AWS::StackName}
          net user administrador ${adminPassword}
          netsh advfirewall set allprofiles state off
          Set-TimeZone -Id "Romance Standard Time" -PassThru
          Invoke-WebRequest "https://apserbucket.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/Recursos/ESET-Windows.zip" -OutFile "C:\Users\Administrador\Desktop\ESET.zip"
          Expand-Archive -Path C:\Users\Administrador\Desktop\ESET.zip -DestinationPath C:\Users\Administrador\Desktop -Force
          C:\Users\Administrador\Desktop\ESMCAgentInstaller.bat
          Get-ChildItem C:\Users\Administrador\Desktop -File -Recurse | Foreach-Object {Remove-Item $_.FullName}
          Restart-Computer -Force
          </powershell>
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Ref 'AWS::StackName'
        - Key: Backup
          Value: true

  securityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupName: !Join
      - ''
      - - SG-
        - !Ref 'AWS::StackName'
      GroupDescription: 'Reglas especificas para este servidor'
      VpcId:
        Ref: vpcId
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Join
            - ''
            - - SG-
              - !Ref 'AWS::StackName'

  elasticIP:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::EIP'
    Properties:
      InstanceId: !Ref server
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Join
            - ''
            - - EIP-
              - !Ref 'AWS::StackName'
```

The funny thing is, that this script worked perfectly not so long ago.

Comment: Can you login to the instance and check log files?

Comment: The thing is that, since the PowerShell Script doesn't execute (or fails at some point), I can't log in with session manager and somehow (even with por 3389 open) I can't RDP into the instance. In other words, I'm blind.

Also, if create a server without the bootstrap, and copy-paste the commands into a power shell, they work just fine.

Comment: You can view the system log through the AWS console and also get an instance screenshot (right-click on the instance in the EC2 console and go to instance settings). Maybe that helps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I could not find out why the PowerShell script was not executing from the user data. The solution was to upload that script to an S3 bucket, and download it then run it from the user data.

It's been two years, but I hope this helps somebody.